# WordPress url parameters with ampersand result in a 404

Tags: wordpress, url, parameters, http-status-code-404

I have a WordPress (4.7.5) setup and trying to pass some URL parameters to a landing page.

`/landingpage/?ID=1779` - Works as expected

`/landingpage/?ID=1779&name=james` - Results in a 404 error page

`/landingpage/?ID=1779&name=james&company=microsoft` - Results in a 404 error page

My question is why does the '&' result in a 404 and how do I get around this?

Thank you for any input x

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not on "ampersand" in your url. But it's the query parameter "name". Change is into something more unique because Wordpress has default query parameters that you should not use in a custom query.

Bellow are default wordpress query vars that you can't use.

```
Array
(
    [error] => 
    [m] => 
    [p] => 0
    [post_parent] => 
    [subpost] => 
    [subpost_id] => 
    [attachment] => 
    [attachment_id] => 0
    [name] => 
    [static] => 
    [pagename] => 
    [page_id] => 0
    [second] => 
    [minute] => 
    [hour] => 
    [day] => 0
    [monthnum] => 0
    [year] => 0
    [w] => 0
    [category_name] => 
    [tag] => 
    [cat] => 
    [tag_id] => 
    [author] => 
    [author_name] => 
    [feed] => 
    [tb] => 
    [paged] => 0
    [meta_key] => 
    [meta_value] => 
    [preview] => 
    [s] => 
    [sentence] => 
    [title] => 
    [fields] => 
    [menu_order] => 
    [embed] => 
    [category__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [category__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [category__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [post__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [post__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [post_name__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag_slug__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag_slug__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [post_parent__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [post_parent__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [author__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [author__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
    [suppress_filters] => 
    [cache_results] => 1
    [update_post_term_cache] => 1
    [lazy_load_term_meta] => 1
    [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
    [post_type] => 
    [posts_per_page] => 10
    [nopaging] => 
    [comments_per_page] => 50
    [no_found_rows] => 
    [order] => DESC
)
```

Comment: If you want to understand why this happens read the docs:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#overview